# Push view Controller in the tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image: Main Tab Bar Controller]

I have three tab bar items in the tab bar now, and I want to let the second one push a navigation controller instead of the default effect. I've tried put `self.navigationController?.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true` in `viewWillAppear` and it didn't work very well.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From the image it's clear you are using storyboards. 
Select the second view controller, the one that you want to navigate to. Then from the file menu select Editor-> Embed in -> Navigation controller. 
Select the segue and then select the segue type as push. 
That should do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually, I've let the view controller embed in a navigation controller. I just don't want let it show directly when tapping the tab bar item, instead, I want it to show with animation like `pushViewController`.